# Filter using Checkboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have this website: http://ba.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/table.html

As you can see, I have two tables. What I need, if it is possible, is to hide and display the tables in the same position using some checkboxes like "table 1" and "table 2".

I think that I have to put the 2 tables in the same `<div>`, but then what?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a few ways but here is what pops into mind:

Give each table an individual ID (id="table1" and id="table2").

Then create your two checkboxes and give them unique ID's.

```
$('#checkbox1').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#table1').toggle($('#checkbox1').is(":checked"));
});
$('#checkbox2').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#table2').toggle($('#checkbox2').is(":checked"));
});
```

You could get more dynamic with the JavaScript but if I understand your question correctly then this should work.